# Using Bootstrap 3 to style/layout user summary box

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to accomplish a (fairly) simple layout with TB3 and am having some difficulty.

I'm trying to create repeatable boxes that I call "user summaries", where each summary box looks like:

[image]

Where:

- The empty square box on the left is a photo of a user
- The top rectangle is the user's display name ("*DonaldDoo*")
- The bottom rectangle is the user's description ("*Dreamed a dozen donuts.*")

Note: I'm not looking for actual borders here (no black borders), that graphic above simply helps depict the layout I am striving for.

Anyways, here's my best attempt thus far:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
        <div>
            <img src="user_photo_here.png" />
            <i>DonaldDoo</i>
            <b>Dreamed a dozen donuts.</b>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="another_user_photo.png" />
            <i>WalterWiggins2000</i>
            <b>Washes Waldo Woo.</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However this does not display correctly. Any ideas where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will fit your requirements. I've replaced the `<b>` and `<i>` tags with `<div>` and assigned classes to them.

Take a look at the snippet.

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
div.user-summary {
  margin: 10px auto;
}
div.user-summary > img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
div.user-name {
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  font-style: italic;
  display: block;
}
div.user-status {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <div class="user-summary clearfix">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/616542814319415296/McCTpH_E.jpg" />
      <div class="user-name">DonaldDoo</div>
      <div class="user-status">Dreamed a dozen donuts</div>
    </div>
    <div class="user-summary clearfix">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/616542814319415296/McCTpH_E.jpg" />
      <div class="user-name">WalterWiggins2000</div>
      <div class="user-status">Washes Waldo Woo.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```